# Can't import package from virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a one-line script in my project which imports a package (flask_mail). I'm running it in virtualenv. If I execute `python script.py` I get `ImportError: No module named flask_mail`. If in the same folder, with the same virtualenv activated I open the python console and run the same command from my `script.py` file (`import flask_mail`) I get no errors whatsoever.

Virtualenv was created with the following command: `virtualenv venv` and then activated `source venv/bin/activate`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you open the python console? Does adding `import sys; print sys.executable` print the same path as doing the same in the console?

Comment: running the cmd in console gives the venv path which is the correct one but running the script returns the global python path. I don't know why.

Comment: You are not using the same python then. `python` is still finding the global python, your virtual env is not active. I also asked you how you are opening the python console.

Comment: Obviously not but it says active in my console when running the script with venv activated....

Comment: You should probably do `cd venv` then `source bin/activate`; I don't think it'll make a difference here though.

Comment: Forget the activate script. Run your script using the virtualenv's python absolute path and check it out. If that works something is messing with your `$PATH`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769541/cant-import-in-a-virtual-enviroment