# What else can I do to troubleshoot a package not importing in python yet imports in ipython while in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenvwrapper

I am a Python enthusiast who decided to get serious about creating some of my own reusable packages.

Synopsis of my problem:

1. Calling `python test_dummy.py` fails to import a package `eforest`. An ImportError is thrown.
2. `import eforest` in the python interpreter and in the **ipython** interpreter both throw no exceptions.
3. Calling `run test_dummy.py` within the **ipython** interpreter throws no exception.
4. All cases are run inside of a virtualenv.

## virtualenv has nothing to do with my problem. I have posted a new question: [script that adds packages to sys.path import as expected when run from ipython but throw exception when the script is run from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606532/script-that-adds-packages-to-sys-path-import-as-expected-when-run-from-ipython-b?noredirect=1#comment40000897_25606532)

A similar question is at [Can't import package from virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308862/cant-import-package-from-virtualenv)

I read the documentation on `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` and installed them both on a Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS system with Python 2.7.6.

I created a virtualenv:

```
mkvirtualenv module_troubleshooting -a . -r requirements.txt
```

My `requirements.txt` file contained:

```
Django==1.6.6
EasyProcess==0.1.6
PyVirtualDisplay==0.1.5
South==1.0
argparse==1.2.1
ipython==2.2.0
lxml==3.3.5
selenium==2.42.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I activated my virtualenv with `workon module_troubleshooting`

My virtualenv was active: `(module_troubleshooting)dmmmd@ubuntuG5:`

I understood from the virtualenvwrapper documentation that I could add packages to the sys.path via the `add2virtualenv` command.

Using `add2virtualenv` I added my very simple packages I had created. I verified that indeed the pth file contained those packages.

```
/home/dmmmd/development/python/singleton
/home/dmmmd/development/python/display
/home/dmmmd/development/python/browser
/home/dmmmd/development/python/eforest
/home/dmmmd/development/python/dummy
```

I ran `ipython` to see if I could import those packages. I could. No errors. Examining the `sys.path` in **ipython** revealed that the above paths were present.

For my own edification I made the following module called test_dummy.py:

```
import browser
import display
import singleton
import eforest
```

I ran the following command in **ipython**: `run test_dummy.py`.

No exceptions in **ipython**.

I then exited **ipython** and ran the following command to assure myself that the global python was NOT being called and to see if python would run the script: `/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin/python test_dummy.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tests/test_dummy.py", line 4, in <module>
import eforest
ImportError: No module named eforest
```

Three other packages, browser, display, and singleton imported as expected and the exception was thrown at **import eforest**

At first, I theorized that eforest might contain some exception. So I ran `/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin/python` and had an expected prompt and no import errors when importing eforest:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:57:26)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import eforest
>>> print eforest
<module 'eforest' from 'eforest/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

So then I theorized that the sys.path for **ipython** and python might be different. I saved the sys.path for python to a file and edited it to the following so the list from `sys.path` could be imported:

```
/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.path" > path.py
```

I edited path.py so that `from path import path` would be the list `sys.path` from calling `/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin/python`.

I then ran **ipython** and typed the following commands:

```
In [1]: from path import path

In [2]: path # this is the sys.path from calling /home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin/python
Out[2]:
['',
 '/home/dmmmd/development/python/singleton',
 '/home/dmmmd/development/python/eforest',
 '/home/dmmmd/development/python/dummy',
 '/home/dmmmd/development/python/display',
 '/home/dmmmd/development/python/browser',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc-linux-gnu',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

To see if **ipython**'s `sys.path` was different I typed:

```
In [5]: import sys

In [6]: len(sys.path)
Out[6]: 19

In [7]: len(path)
Out[7]: 16

In [8]: [item for item in sys.path if item not in path]
Out[8]:
['/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin',
 '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/dmmmd/.ipython']
```

The last two items of **ipython**'s sys.path are **ipython** related. The one different item is '/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin'.

Can anybody offer any other troubleshooting advice or explain to me how having **'/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin'** in the sys.path in **ipython** allows eforest to import as expected in **ipython** when `run test_dummy.py` is called?

eforest package:

```
eforest/
├── CustomElementFilters.py
├── CustomEtrees.py
├── CustomEtrees.pyc
├── __init__.py
└── __init__.pyc
```

Again, eforest imports as expected in **ipython** and with the python interpreter but it does not import when a script passed as the argument to `/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin/python test_dummy.py`.

The only possible exception to eforest that comes to my mind that is different from the other packages is that it imports lxml. Could lxml depend somehow on having **'/home/dmmmd/.virtualenvs/module_troubleshooting/bin'** in the sys.path?

Any suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. I first noticed the problem when I was using py.test. I thought it had something to do with py.test, but as it turned out the test scripts I was writing didn't run with python either. I decided to stop there and see if I could get some help.

## Ruled out virtualenv as a problem source

I ran the following script with `python test_dummy.py` with the virtuenv **deactivated**.

```
import sys
import os
HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
PYTHON = os.path.join(HOME, 'development/my_python')
PACKAGES = [
    'browser',
    'display',
    'singleton',
    'eforest'
]
for package in PACKAGES:
    package = os.path.join(PYTHON, package)
    if os.path.exists(package) is True:
        if package not in sys.path:
            print "loading package '{0}'".format(package)
            sys.path.append(package)
        else:
            print "package '{0}' already in sys.path".format(package)
    else:
        raise
import browser
import display
import singleton
import eforest
```

With the virtualenv **deactivated** `eforest` is the only package that does not import with running the `python test_dummy.py` command.

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_django/automated_browsing/tests/test_dummy.py", line 16, in <module>
import eforest
ImportError: No module named eforest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution although the solution does not solve the problem of why certain package paths added in an *ad hoc* fashion to `sys.path` are not imported when the script is run with `python test_dummy.py`.

I originally ran into this problem while trying to use py.test. [In the py.test documentation I saw this tip](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managing_python_path.html#managing-your-project-with-virtualenv-pip-and-editable-mode) about "managing your project with virutalenv, pip, and editable mode." I ignored it because I thought it was too advanced for my level of Python knowledge.

I decided to try the tip after reading about "[creating your own python project](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-your-own-project)."

In the pwd I created a `setup.py` file with the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='import_troubleshooting', version='1.0')
packages = find_packages(exclude=[
    'my_django',
    'fake*',
    'tests*'
])
```

I then executed the following code at the command line:

```
pip install -e .  # the pip way (which just calls "setup.py develop")
```

I then executed the following code with the expected results:

```
$ python tests/test_dummy.py
# output    
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/browser' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/display' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/singleton' already in sys.path
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/test_a'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/hello_world'
loading 'browser'
loading 'display'
loading 'singleton'
loading 'test_a'
loading 'hello_world.hello'
Hello, world!
```

None of this explains to me why I couldn't add the package paths in an *ad hoc* fashion. I am pleased, however, to have learned something about python installation and packaging. The `test_dummy.py` script now runs as expected when called from `python tests/test_dummy.py`.

I am now confused as to why three of the packages are already in `sys.path` when the `test_dummy.py` script is run:

```
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/browser' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/display' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/singleton' already in sys.path
```

I don't recall doing anything that would add those to `sys.path` but it is possible since I have been doing various tutorials. They are not in `sys.path` in any other environment where I have not run the `setup.py` that I created.

My confusion is a symptom of the complexity of Python, not a cause!

Thank you for everybody's input.

## NB: This is the output of `python test_dummy.py` after a fresh virtualenv:

```
$ pip install -e .
# install output unremarkable
$ python tests/test_dummy.py
# output
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/browser'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/display'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/singleton'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/hello_world'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/test_a'
loading 'browser'
loading 'display'
loading 'singleton'
loading 'hello_world.hello'
Hello, world!
loading 'test_a'
```