# script that adds packages to sys.path import as expected when run from ipython but throw exception when the script is run from python

Tags: python, ipython, setuptools, ubuntu-14.04

I am a perplexed Python enthusiast. I posted [What else can I do to troubleshoot a package not importing in python yet imports in ipython while in a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587672/what-else-can-i-do-to-troubleshoot-a-package-not-importing-in-python-yet-imports) thinking that I was having a problem with my virtualenv. Some more troubleshooting has revealed this is probably not the case.

I would appreciate any insight or troubleshooting tips so that I can get on with package development. Thank you in advance!

Synopsis of my problem on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS system with Python 2.7.6.:

1. I have a script named test_dummy.py that adds package paths to sys.path and then attempts to import the packages.
2. The packages import without error when the script is run with `run test_dummy.py` inside of **ipython**.
3. ImportError exceptions are thrown for certain packages when the script is run with `python test_dummy.py`.
4. What is most frustrating is that the packages that contain code i.e. more than just an `__init__.py` file import without exception. Simple test packages with only a `__init__.py` file in them do not import as expected. I cannot determine what is causing the simplest of packages to throw exceptions on import when the script is called from python i.e. `python test_dummy.py`.

My pwd is as such:

```
.
├── browser
├── display
├── hello_world
├── singleton
├── test_a
└── tests
```

test_a is as such:

```
test_a
├── __init__.py
└── __init__.pyc
```

hello_world is as such:

```
hello_world/
├── hello.py
├── hello.pyc
├── __init__.py
└── __init__.pyc
```

hello.py is as such:

```
HELLO = 'Hello, world!'
print HELLO
```

The other packages ['browser', 'display', 'singleton'] all contain **init**.py files and other code that throws no known exceptions when run.

tests is as such:

```
tests
└── test_dummy.py
```

The code in test_dummy.py:

```
import importlib
import os
import sys
HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
PYTHON = os.path.join(HOME, 'development/my_python')
PACKAGES = [
    'browser',
    'display',
    'singleton',
    'test_a',
    'hello_world',
]
MODULES = [
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'hello',
]
IMPORTS = ['.'.join((pkg, module)).strip('.')
           for pkg, module
           in zip(PACKAGES, MODULES)]
"""
append sys.path with PACKAGES if package exists and not already
in the sys.path
"""
for package in PACKAGES:
    package = os.path.join(PYTHON, package)
    if os.path.exists(package) is True:
        if package not in sys.path:
            print "loading package '{0}'".format(package)
            sys.path.append(package)
        else:
            print "package '{0}' already in sys.path".format(package)
    else:
        message = "Package '{0}' does not exist.".format(package)
        raise IOError(message)
"""
import IMPORTS if the package is in sys.path
"""
for item in IMPORTS:
    pkg_in_path = [pkg == os.path.basename(path)
                   for pkg in PACKAGES for path in sys.path]
    if any(pkg_in_path):
        print "loading '{0}'".format(item)
        importlib.import_module(item)
    else:
        raise AttributeError("{0} not in sys.path".format(item))
```

**ipython** results:

```
$ ipython
# result
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:57:26)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
Warning: disable autoreload in ipython_config.py to improve performance.

In [3]: run tests/test_dummy.py
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/browser'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/display'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/singleton'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/test_a'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/hello_world'
loading 'browser'
loading 'display'
loading 'singleton'
loading 'test_a'
loading 'hello_world.hello'
Hello, world!
```

results from `python tests/test_dummy.py`:

```
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/browser'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/display'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/singleton'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/test_a'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/hello_world'
loading 'browser'
loading 'display'
loading 'singleton'
loading 'test_a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_dummy.py", line 46, in <module>
    importlib.import_module(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named test_a
```

Importing the package 'test_a' in the python interpreter does not throw an exception:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:57:26)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/test_a')
>>> import test_a
>>> print test_a
<module 'test_a' from 'test_a/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

Comment: How does `__init__.py` in `test_a` looks? And in `browser`?

Comment: browser/__init__.py contains a comment and `from browser import Firefox`. In test_a, the __init__.py is empty.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, did you try adding some code to the `test_a` or changing `browser` folder name to `test_a` and see if it's imported?

Comment: It is a perplexing problem definitely beyond my limited knowledge. See the answer I posted. Thank you for your help, t.pimentel. I did try changing the names of `test_a` and `browser`. Exceptions were still thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution although the solution does not solve the problem of why certain package paths added in an *ad hoc* fashion to `sys.path` are not imported when the script is run with `python test_dummy.py`.

I originally ran into this problem while trying to use py.test. [In the py.test documentation I saw this tip](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managing_python_path.html#managing-your-project-with-virtualenv-pip-and-editable-mode) about "managing your project with virutalenv, pip, and editable mode." I ignored it because I thought it was too advanced for my level of Python knowledge.

I decided to try the tip after reading about "[creating your own python project](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-your-own-project)."

In the pwd I created a `setup.py` file with the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='import_troubleshooting', version='1.0')
packages = find_packages(exclude=[
    'my_django',
    'fake*',
    'tests*'
])
```

I then executed the following code at the command line:

```
pip install -e .  # the pip way (which just calls "setup.py develop")
```

I then executed the following code with the expected results:

```
$ python tests/test_dummy.py
# output    
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/browser' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/display' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/singleton' already in sys.path
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/test_a'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/hello_world'
loading 'browser'
loading 'display'
loading 'singleton'
loading 'test_a'
loading 'hello_world.hello'
Hello, world!
```

None of this explains to me why I couldn't add the package paths in an *ad hoc* fashion without first installing my packages with `pip install -e .`. It is strange, too, that the failure is only when passing the script to `python`. `ipython test_dummy.py` works **without installing my local packages first**.

I am pleased, however, to have learned something about python installation and packaging. The `test_dummy.py` script now runs as expected when called from `python tests/test_dummy.py`.

I am now confused as to why three of the packages are already in `sys.path` when the `test_dummy.py` script is run:

```
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/browser' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/display' already in sys.path
package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/singleton' already in sys.path
```

I don't recall doing anything that would add those to `sys.path` but it is possible since I have been doing various tutorials. They are not in `sys.path` in any other environment where I have not run the `setup.py` that I created.

My confusion is a symptom of the complexity of Python, not a cause!

Thank you for everybody's input.

## NB: This is the output of `python test_dummy.py` after a fresh virtualenv:

```
$ pip install -e .
# install output unremarkable
$ python tests/test_dummy.py
# output
    loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/browser'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/display'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/singleton'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/hello_world'
loading package '/home/dmmmd/development/my_python/automated_browsing/test_a'
loading 'browser'
loading 'display'
loading 'singleton'
loading 'hello_world.hello'
Hello, world!
loading 'test_a'
```